# Why does connecting to my work VPN still cause my internet to not work?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I'm connecting to a VPN for work, when I connect I am not able to browse the internet locally.  I have unchecked ["Use default gateway on remote network"](https://superuser.com/questions/313921/why-does-connecting-to-my-work-vpn-cause-my-internet-to-not-work) to enable split tunneling in the TCP/IPv4 advanced settings for the VPN connection.

I am running Windows 7 Professional and have checked that the ["Route all traffic through the internal network"](http://www.groovypost.com/forum/windows7/vpn-connects-but-there-are-issues-t95959.html#p97202) setting in gpedit is not enabled. (It's set to not configured)

What can I try next to resolve this?

Comment: What is the output of `route print` while connected? This should show us how Windows is making its routing decisions.

Comment: Usually the admin of the VPN gateway of your work company can set if all traffic is routed through VPN or not. This overrides all local policies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `route print` showed two sets of 0.0.0.0 default gateways.

This happened because Apple's iTunes was previously installed.  Even though it had been removed a long time ago, the issue remained.
See [The Bonjour service set the Default Gateway to 0.0.0.0.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970313)

Microsoft says

> This problem occurs because Bonjour uses logic to add a route to
>   specify a default gateway of 0.0.0.0 which it does not remove.
>
> The following events must happen to receive this route, on a computer
>   running Windows Vista or higher, with Bonjour installed:
>
> The computer does not receive an address through DHCP prior to the
>   Bonjour service start.
>
> Under this condition, the Bonjour service adds a default route to the
>   computer indicating that all internet hosts are “onlink”.
>
> The computer is subsequently able to receive an address through DHCP.
>   Bonjour does not remove the default route, leaving an incorrect
>   default gateway configured on the machine. This gateway usurps the
>   proper gateway configuration DHCP provides and prevents internet
>   access.

Running the Microsoft FixIt and recreating the VPN fixed the issue.