# Windows 8.1 VPN connection to customer's network blocks access to local domain's shares, SQL Server

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn, sql-server, windows-domain

With Windows 7, I could access my company's Windows Server file shares and SQL Servers (with Windows authentication) from that same LAN while connected to my customer's VPN.  With Windows 8.1, I lose the ability to connect to my domain's own shares and (with Windows authentication) SQL Servers while connected directly to my company's LAN and connected to my customer's VPN.  I can connect to the VPN and then connect using SQL authentication to local SQL Servers, but Windows Authentication fails.

Example:

```
C:\>NET VIEW \\servername
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

As soon I disconnect from the VPN, I'm able to access these domain resources.

I'm using the VPN client included with Windows 8.1 to connect to PPTP VPN.  I've not selected the option to "Automatically use my Windows logon name and password."

Perhaps once the VPN connection is made, further authentication requests are made using the credentials provided for the VPN connection rather than the domain credentials with which I logged into my own PC.  This seems like a useful feature that didn't get its control function surfaced in the VPN connection properties UI.  There's got to be a way to switch this off.

Thanks for your input.

EDIT:  Contrary to suggestions, this does not duplicate "[Why does connecting to my work VPN cause my internet to not work?](https://superuser.com/questions/313921/why-does-connecting-to-my-work-vpn-cause-my-internet-to-not-work)".  That question described loss of access to the Internet, while this describes loss of access to the intranet.

Comment: Thanks Techie007 for that prompt reply!  The referenced question refers to an inability to access the hosts on the Internet.  In my case, I'm having trouble accessing the Intranet--servers on the same LAN as my PC--after the VPN connection is made.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Robinson Zhang who [addressed this issue back in 2008](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/275599f0-6239-46a5-8245-50a5c13a2713/vista-connects-to-vpn-then-fails-windows-authentication-for-sql-iis-on-local-lan-sspi?forum=itprovistanetworking).  His solution was to specify `UseRasCredentials=0` in the VPN connection's PBK file.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, providing the link for reference?  This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page changes or goes offline.  Microsoft has a history of moving links, and old links are not set up to be redirected, resulting in dead links in the future.