# On connecting to the VPN first internet fails, then I can't access the resource on VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, routing

I have the same problem as the last answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/313921/why-does-connecting-to-my-work-vpn-cause-my-internet-to-not-work?newreg=f45a3f103ea6477a8ba47dba6373a50a).

On connecting to the VPN I lost my internet access, so I unchecked "Use default gateway on unchecked network". 
 But then I can't access the resource that I want on the VPN as well (reason to use the VPN in the first place).
So I tried running this command:

```
route -p add 172.18.1.101 mask 255.255.255.255 10.217.77.1
```

But I still cannot access the resources on the VPN.

ipconfig after connecting to the VPN returns this:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gdnindia.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b9e2:8093:29dc:3a81%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.217.77.73
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.217.77.66
```

My IP configurations of the VPN:
[image: IP details of VPN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I was not giving DNS address.
In networking -> Ipv4 -> Use the following address as DNS.
Nothing to do with Adding route in route table.

Comment: which *following* DNS ? :)

Comment: Its a checkbox.